# Neo4j : Performance issue

Tags: neo4j

We are using Neo4j 3.4 Enterprise Edition as our application’s data store. It is running on EC2 instance with an 8 core CPU and 16GB RAM.

We have uploaded these datasets :

1. Sales: Consists of facts like Dollars, Discount, Volume and Price per Volume etc., visualized against dimensions Brand, Week and Business Unit etc.
2. Weather:  Consists of facts Temperature, Precipitation and Snowfall, visualized against dimensions Day, Month and Weather Station
3. Media: Consists of facts Spend, TRPs and Impression, visualized against dimensions Week, Business Unit, Brand, Channel, Audience and Campaign

It is a generic model that we have designed that could accommodate different types of datasets.

The model is based on the following Arrow diagram -

[image: Domain Diagram]

[Arrow Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oac2g.png)

The type of queries we are running on it are not dependent on the type of application that dataset belongs to. It is a general use case wherein we are trying to fetch all details related to events that happened at same ‘time’ or ‘location’.

Design philosophy :

1. Each node represents a row of data in the fact table. The values of those facts are captured as properties. If a dataset has 2 million rows in fact table, it will have 2 million corresponding nodes following the pattern above. Check PosSales node.
2. On what basis did we create relationships – all measures from one dataset are on the same node as properties, while dimensions are connected to the nodes. Each dimension is a separate node.
3. Conformed dimensions for time and location are used to establish paths/relationships between disparate datasets like Sales, Weather and Media Delivery - time, location, or dataset specific dimensions

We are looking to perform JOINs between these above-mentioned datasets. The result set should return an INNER JOIN between these three mentioned datasets to present say, one fact each from the three datasets, like these – Dollar Sales, Daily Weather, and Impression. These would be presented grouped by a combination of dimensions from all three datasets.
The database has 1M Nodes and 2M relationships.

Neo4j is configured to use maximum up to 80% of total system memory 16 GB.
Apparent problem –

Our queries are running into combinatorial explosion as highlighted in below diagram. We looked at query execution plan that reflects count of db above 100M hits in few stages.

[image]
[Arrow Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnpbn.png)

Here are few statistics of each labels

1. PosSales – 178k nodes
2. SKU_IRI – 237 nodes
3. SKU_Dist – 90 nodes
4. DistributorShipments – 680k nodes

We want to get facts from two datasets i.e. Sales and Shipments. When we connect PosSales and DistributorShipments nodes through SKU_IRI and SKU_Dist, combinatorial explosion is happening.

How should we address the combinatorial explosion?

Is there any better ways of modeling our graph to avoid these types of issues?

Is there some configuration or setting that I can tweak on Neo4j server that can allow it to use more RAM and CPU which are clearly underutilized, so that queries run faster?

[Attaching document which has few sample queries](https://docs.google.com/document/d/159-MroRGH7wSVTgovVvlA7i5ILxE_Qsap2j9qoQhzkw/edit)

Comment: I would not use a those generic relationships like `CONNECTED` or `CONTAINS` if you use concrete ones that encode the end node Neo4j can more efficiently pre-filter those.

Comment: Your queries have no restrictions at all, they pull in the whole database. Is that intentional? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would not use a those generic relationships like CONNECTED or CONTAINS if you use concrete ones that encode the end node Neo4j can more efficiently pre-filter those.

 - Accepted. We will make the change and update this thread.

Comment: Your queries have no restrictions at all, they pull in the whole database. Is that intentional? What do you want to achieve?
- It is intentional. We want to give user the ability to perform JOINs on possibly hundreds of thousands of datasets uploaded. To give an example, the user has selected a variable called 'Dollar Sales' on web application UI. The user thinks that she can improve predictions for that variable, if she had historic weather and consumer price index (CPI) data too. Now these three were uploaded to Neo4j from different datasets.

Comment: Each having its own grain, we could establish common paths between these on either location or time basis. Dollar Sales is at city level per day. Weather/temperature is at city level per hour. CPI is at country level per quarter. She wants to perform an equivalent of LEFT JOIN using graph. At application level we have to generate the corresponding Cypher. Those nodes could be anywhere in the graph. If the user wants to filter the data returned based on specific time (E.g. year/month) and/or location (country/city), we put a WHERE clause in Cypher.

Comment: Like the example above, JOINs could happen using either location or time between any two datasets that capture valuable metrics.